# How can I numerate list items using State monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

**Problem:**

I am trying to understand [state-monad](/questions/tagged/state-monad).

A bit stuck to understand how can I use it, and I am looking for some example.

Let's say I want to implement a function `[()] -> [Int]`:

```
numerate :: [()] -> [Int]
```

Should I map each element of the list to state and then fold it?

How can I do it using `State`?

**Expected behavior:**

```
numerate [(), (), (), (), ()]
-- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Sorry. It is not clear for me what your problem is...

Comment: I thought to start with something like map (\_ -> modify(+1)) xs, but then... After fold how can back to list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can implement a `State` object that will increment the state and return it, like:

```
incState :: State Int Int
incState = modify (1+) >> get
```

Then we can run this `State Int Int` over the list, like:

```
numerate :: (Traversable t) => t a -> t Int
numerate = flip evalState 0 . traverse (const incState)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State> numerate Nothing
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad.State> numerate (Just 'a')
Just 1
Prelude Control.Monad.State> numerate (Just 0)
Just 1
Prelude Control.Monad.State> numerate [1,4,2,5]
[1,2,3,4]
Prelude Control.Monad.State> numerate [(), (), ()]
[1,2,3]
```

We can also work with other traversable structures, like a [**`Tree`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Tree) for example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State Data.Tree> numerate (Node 'a' [Node 'b' [], Node 'c' []])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 2, subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = 3, subForest = []}]}
```

Comment: Does `>>` operator in `modify (1+) >> get` ignore the previous state?

Comment: @mkUltra: no, `>>` omits the outcome of the previous `State s a` (so an `a`), but since `modify (1+)` is a `State Int ()`, there is no outcome anyway.

Comment: I am wondering, is it possible to do the same using only MonadWriter?